# How to search by Russian Language from database Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

This is my query of searching through database Laravel 5.5

```
$search = $request->get('search');
$projects = new Project();
$projects = $projects->where('description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
    ->paginate(10)
    ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

[image: This is the error i tried to search by АБВГД]

Comment: datetime fields gives error for Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'. remove `->orWhere('created_at', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')` this line

Comment: then how to search from 2 columnes i need search from created_at too

Comment: did you try removing that line?? is it worked or not?? after that we can go ahead.

Comment: it worked for description column

Comment: use date_format()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your problem is that `datetime` fields gives error for Illegal mix of collations for operation `'like'`. Use `DATE_FORMAT()` to make it operational.

```
$projects = $projects->where('description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '%$search%'")
->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
->paginate(10)
->withPath('?search=' . $search);
```

Comment: `date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given`